# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,5,2) into shape (5,2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A n-dimensional array which is initialised as

```
features=np.empty(shape=(100,5,2), dtype=float)
```

and I am trying to add 3D array into it as

```
features[i,:] = features_next
```

features_next has shape (2,5,2).
However, it shows error,

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,5,2) into shape (5,2).
```

here is the piece of code :

```
   features=np.empty(shape=((historical*2),5,2), dtype=float)  
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        state = self.getDictState(state_index)
        asks = state['asks']
        bids = state['bids']
        features_next = self.getNormalisedFeature(
            bids=bids,
            asks=asks,
            state_index=state_index,
            qty=qty,
            price=price,
            size=size,
            normalize=normalize,
            levels=levels
        )
        '''if i == 0:
            features = np.array(features_next)
        else:
            features = np.vstack((features, features_next))'''
        features[i,:] = features_next
        state_index = (state_index - 1)
    return features
```

Note : I am trying to replace commented 'if condition' with features[i,:] = features_next to make the code execution bit faster.

Comment: If `i` is a single integer, you're accessing a `features` with a (1, 5, 2) indexing shape, which is indeed not compatible with (2, 5, 2).

Comment: So you'll have to decide whether you want to lose a dimension of `features_next` (e.g., `features[i, ...] = features_next[0, ...]`), or index into two (first) dimensions of `features` (e.g., like `features[3:5, ...] = features_next`).

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, just one point to make `features[i,:]` has shape (5, 2) and feature_next has shape (2, 5, 2). I want to say that both are compatible shapes. But broadcasting is done on a smaller shape over a larger shape. SO there is error since you are doing revere. Also look up on broadcasting on numpy docs.

Next, this one I think will do

This does not directly solve your problem, but has some ideas about what you can try, like you can reshape your array before going in loop using `features.shape = (50, 2, 5, 2)`.

```py
import numpy as np

features=np.empty(shape=(100,5,2), dtype=float)
features_next = np.random.random((2, 5, 2))

features.shape = ((50, 2, 5, 2)) 

features[:] = features_next
features.shape = (100, 5, 2)
```